What electronic component is this, mark "AS41" "AR41""E40"
I recently came across several power chips that only had the chip printed on them, but I didn't know what model they were. These three chips are from a Japanese manufacturer.  The picture is as follows.




https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710/91862

Signs point to the first two being Ricoh RP173 regulators, with the AR41 being the RP173Q412A (with ~CE enable pin) and the AS41 being RP173Q412B (with CE).

Do you have a datasheet link with markings?

@vivier no, the datasheet says to find markings info on a website that AFAICT no longer exists. I used a combination of info from an SMD marking database, and inference from a PDF I was able to find that covers the SOT23 version of the same part.

OK, in the "SMD databook" that's right! Also I found the marking style hereafter: http://nisdt.co.th/nisdt/Semiconductor.asp  (in SC-88). Ricoh is now Nisshinbo. I'm convinced now, +1.

The third one is manufactured by Mitsumi aka MinebeaMitsumi aka NMBTC. The package is SC-82 which they use for reset ICs, shunt regulators and discharge ICs according to this product page.
Here is a picture from their site that shows the marking style:

(Source: nmbtc.com)
Mitsumi doesn't specify markings and there are very few pictures around, so I think your best bet is to ask Mitsumi directly if you want to know the exact model.
There is also this related question that asks about a similar IC marked H30 for which I gave pretty much the same answer.

yes ,it is Mitsumi
